# as a gitlab admin, how can I list all recent activity

Tags: gitlab

Generally, activity reports are limited to those projects or groups we are a member of; however, as the admin for a gitlab site, sometimes, when doing upgrades for example, it would be convenient to see if and where any recent activity was. I saw nothing in either the gui or the gitlab-shell or rake commands to do this.

Comment: What do you consider as activity? have you looked at the logs under `/log/`? S Most logs are also visible from the admin panel, but it is just a copy paste from those files.

Comment: In Gitlab, as admin, go to `Admin`>`Logs`>`Application` : you will see here all projects creation, users creation etc. with the date

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a newbie at gitlab, I should have thought of checking the logs. And you're both right, the application log contains the information I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After checking the logs, here is the lowdown:

The application log only contains information for git activities: push and pull operations, commits, etc.

The only information available about issues and other parts of the system are in the nginx (or apache) access logs, by checking the POST operations.